# Inheritance and compilation C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, compilation

Please explain me the relations (if there are any) between the inheritance and need for recompilation in C++.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668994/data-isolation-between-pure-abstract-class-against-its-implmentation-and-the-tru) (namely, second and third paragraphs of it), answers to this question and now I am confused about what and why should be  recompiled (and should be recompiled at all?) when changes are made in base class implementation...

In particular, I thought that compilation has to deal only with translation units - I cannot, for example, understand how *class hierarchy* or *class* can be recompiled. But it is stated in the question, that they can, and not refuted by the answers. Aren't these translation units, *which only* can be compiled/recompiled?

If there is really any connection between changes to base classes and need for recompilation of some parts of a program, explain it me, please, and give some brief examples if possible (in particular, if there is really such a connection, I would like to know a difference between abstract classes and "usual" base classes from this point of view).

Comment: While translation units and possible recomplation of source files are somewhat related, it's totally unrelated to the subject of inheritance. However, one way inheritance could actually affect recompilation is if the base class is defined in a header file that is includes by the header file for the child class. Then all source files that depend on the child-class header file *also* depend on the header file for the base class. A change in the header file for the base class should trigger recompilation of all source file depending in it, even if the dependency is indirect.

Comment: fwiw, the paragraph you refer to ends with "Is my understanding correct?"

Comment: If a translation unit (aka. a C++ source file) is modified the compiler has to compile only this. If a header is changed then all translation units have to be recompiled which `#include` this header (directly or indirectly via other headers). It's simply not more or less than this. Inheritance is related insofar: If you derive one class from another, you have to "know" the base class. For this, it's usual that the file with the derived class decl. has to `#include` the header with the base class decl. Modifications of a C++ source file should be unrelated regardless of any inheritance.

Comment: @idclev463035818, yes, I mean this paragraph

Comment: If you change the source code, the only way to get those changes to be reflected in the program is to recompile those parts (translation units) of the program that have changed.  Header files are also source code, but usually distinguished as the declarative portion of the source code rather than the definition portion of the source code.  Changes to inheritance follows the same process for recompiling.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it sounds much more clearly to me, thank you! But why do the people in that post talk about somewhat difference between abstract class and not-abstract classes in that sense?

Comment: Regarding " A few changes to the implementation of member functions (function signature remains unchanged) of the root class, and you have to recompile the entire class hierarchy to apply changes its terminal classes, otherwise the program breaks." That's not true, unless the implementation is in the header file. If a header file remains unmodified, the translation units depending on that header file doesn't need to be rebuilt.

Comment: i just mentioned it because I think you could provide better information on the context. If someone writes "blablablabla. Is this correct?" it has a different meaning than "blablablabla!". Also, what do the answers to that question say about it?

Comment: @idclev463035818, edited the question - hope it sounds more logical now

Answer (score 0):

`Base.h`

```
class Base {
public:
Base(int i, int o) : _i(i), _o(o) {}
int _i;
int _o;
};
```

`Base.cpp`

```
int Base::foo() {return _i+_o;}
```

`Derived.h`

```
#include "Base.h"
class Derived : public Base {
Derived (int i, int o) : Base(i, o) {
result = foo();
}
int result;
};
```

If you change `Base::foo` such that it now performs as such :

```
int Base::foo() { return _i - _o;}
```

you need not recompile `Base.h` or `Derived.cpp` but you do need to recompile `Base.cpp` because 1/the code in Base.cpp changed (thus requires compilation) and 2/the code in Derived that calls Base::foo() doesn't need to know about changes made to `Base::foo`, it only needs to know that it should call Base::foo with no argument and that the functions returns an int.
Now if you change it as such :

```
int Base::foo(int k) { return _i - k;}
```

You need to recompile `Base.h` because you need to update the function signature and it has to tell `Derived` how to call `Base::foo()`.
You need to recompile `Base.cpp` because its code has changed.
You need to recompile `Derived.h` because it now needs to call `Base::foo(int k)` with one argument.